# Angular + Bootstrap. Get the name of the tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that shows Bootstrap tabs and I want to change it so each tab has it own url. I'm assuming that the Url alone is very simple and I should add the new url to angular router.

How do I get which tab is currently selected?

Comment: where is the code you tried?

Comment: I haven't yet because I'm not sure if I should use jquery. I will try and post it.

Comment: Since you won't be using any tabs scripts all you need is `ng-class`. If you are using `ui-router` can simplify it using `ui-sref-active` directive

Comment: How does it work? The tabs I have working are with Bootstrap. Normal tabs

Comment: All you are using is the markup for the tabs themselves if you have each tab in different route. Either that or it's not clear how you intend to do this

Comment: I want each tab in a different route. That's the target. That's my question

Comment: Just take markup for tabs themselves and set active class based on route. Think *"Tabs Nav"*

Comment: I use the ng-class active to get highlight the selected tab but I can't get the text shown in the tab. I want the text because im using firebase.com and would like create a certain query